# how to use write a correct jsp useBeans

Tags: javascript, jsp, javabeans

What is the different between:

- putting `jsp:setProperty` **inside** `jsp:useBean` tag, and
- putting `jsp:setProperty` **outside** the `jsp:useBean` tag?

Some example code:

```
<jsp:useBean id="user" class="beans.User" scope="session" > 
</jsp:useBean>
<jsp:setProperty property="email" name="user" value="programmingtute.com"/>
<jsp:setProperty property="password" name="user" value="abcdf"/>

<jsp:useBean id="user" class="beans.User" scope="session" >
<jsp:setProperty property="email" name="user" value="programmingtute.com"/>
<jsp:setProperty property="password" name="user" value="abcdf"/>
</jsp:useBean>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1.<:jsp:setProperty> can appear is inside the body of a jsp:useBean element. In this case it executed only if a new object was instantiated, not if an existing one was found.
2.<:jsp:setProperty> can appear is outside and after a jsp:useBean element. In this case it executed on a new object or any found existing bean created earlier.
```